# Error on datatables after first data load

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm going crazy trying to solve this problem.

If I call `setModalRetta` for the first time, all works fine, when I close modal and I click on other data I get an error

> jquery.dataTables.min.js:4
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')) on loading datatables (tableretta = $('#tableretta').DataTable({....).

I put 2 example of objData. Error will fire on second times only if data (objData) change after first call.

Thanks

```
{
    "DataArr": "2022-05-21T00:00:00",
    "DataPart": "2022-05-25T00:00:00",
    "Retta": 328,
    "NumPersone": 1,
    "Nome": "Formula Residence",
    "TipoCamera1": "DELUX",
    "NumCamera": "103",
    "NomeOspite": "KOSEL WALDEMAR ",
    "Giorni": [
        "2022-05-20",
        "2022-05-21",
        "2022-05-22",
        "2022-05-23",
        "2022-05-24"
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "DataArr": "2022-06-06T00:00:00",
    "DataPart": "2022-06-13T00:00:00",
    "Retta": 672,
    "NumPersone": 1,
    "Nome": "Formula Residence",
    "TipoCamera1": "DELUX",
    "NumCamera": "102",
    "NomeOspite": "RACCUGLIA AGATA ",
    "Giorni": [
        "2022-06-05",
        "2022-06-06",
        "2022-06-07",
        "2022-06-08",
        "2022-06-09",
        "2022-06-10",
        "2022-06-11",
        "2022-06-12"
    ]
}
```

```
    $('#mdlRetta').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tableretta')) {
            $('#tableretta').DataTable().destroy();
            console.log('destroied on unload');
            tableretta = null;
        }    
    });

    function setModalRetta(objData) {
        console.log('Avvio Set Modal Retta');
        if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tableretta')) {
            console.log('pre destroy');
            $('#tableretta').DataTable().destroy();
            console.log('Destroyed on load');
        }
        // Creazione del nuovo array JSON con righe duplicate in base a NumPersone
        var duplicatedJson = [];
        objData.forEach(function (item, index) {
            var numPersone = item.NumPersone;
            var originalItem = Object.assign({}, item); // Copia l'elemento originale
            if (numPersone > 1) {
                originalItem.NumPersone = 1;
                duplicatedJson.push(originalItem); // Aggiungi l'elemento originale
                for (var i = 0; i < numPersone - 1; i++) {
                    var newItem = Object.assign({}, item);
                    newItem.NumPersone = 1;
                    newItem.NomeOspite = "Ospite " + (i + 1);
                    duplicatedJson.push(newItem);
                }
            } else {
                duplicatedJson.push(item);
            }
        });
        console.log('Aggiunta ospiti fatta');
        // Aggiunta dell'array "Giorni" a ciascun valore nel JSON
        for (var i = 0; i < duplicatedJson.length; i++) {
            var valore = duplicatedJson[i];
            var dtArr = parseDate(moment(valore.DataArr).format("YYYY-MM-DD"), "-");
            var dtPart = parseDate(moment(valore.DataPart).format("YYYY-MM-DD"), "-");
            valore.Giorni = calcolaGiorni(dtArr, dtPart);
        }


        var giorni = duplicatedJson[0].Giorni; // tutti i valori hanno lo stesso elenco di giorni
        var dynamicColumns = []; // Array per le colonne dinamiche

        //Definisco le colonne della table
        var columns = [

            { data: 'NumCamera', title: 'Camera' },
            { data: 'NomeOspite', title: 'Ospite' },
            { data: 'Retta', title: 'Retta' },
            { data: 'NumPersone', title: 'Numero Persone' },
            { data: 'Nome', title: 'Nome' },
            { data: 'TipoCamera1', title: 'Tipo Camera' },
            { data: 'DataArr', title: 'DataArr' },
            { data: 'DataPart', title: 'DataPart' },

        ];
        //aggiungo le colonne dei giorni
        var naddedcols=0;
        giorni.forEach(function (giorno) {
            var giornoMese = new Date(giorno).toLocaleDateString('it-IT', { day: 'numeric', month: 'numeric' });
            naddedcols++;
            dynamicColumns.push({ data: giorno, title: giornoMese });
        });
        //aggiungo 1 col per il totale ed una 1 in più per il calcolo dinamico della riga
        naddedcols++;
        naddedcols++;
        // Aggiungo la colonna totale

        dynamicColumns.push({ data: "Totale", title: "Totale" });
        // Combina le colonne statiche e dinamiche

        var allColumns = columns.concat(dynamicColumns);

        console.table(duplicatedJson);
        console.table(allColumns);
        var previousValue = null;

        tableretta = $('#tableretta').DataTable({
            data: duplicatedJson,
            columns: allColumns,
            dom: 't',
            columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: '_all',
                defaultContent: '0' // Imposta il valore predefinito a 0 per tutte le celle
            },
                {
                    target: 2,
                    visible: false,
                },
            {
                    target: 3,
                    visible: false,
                },
                {
                    target: 4,
                    visible: false,
                },
                {
                    target: 5,
                    visible: false,
                },
                {
                    target: 6,
                    visible: false,
                },
                {
                    target: 7,
                    visible: false,
                },
            ],
            select: {
                style: 'os',
                items: 'cell'
            },
            scrollX: true,
            orderFixed: [[0, 'asc']],
            "rowCallback": function (row, data, index) {
                var colValue = data[0]; // la colonna da controllare è la prima (0)

                if (colValue === previousValue) {
                    $('td:eq(0)', row).empty(); // Nasconde il valore settando il contenuto della cella come vuoto
                } else {
                    previousValue = colValue;
                }
            },
            "drawCallback": function () {
                var api = this.api();
                nb_cols = api.columns().nodes().length;
                
                api.rows().every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
                    var mySum = 0;                    
                    var cells = "-" + naddedcols;
                    $('td:gt('+cells+'):not(:last-child)', this.node()).each(function () {
                        mySum += parseFloat($(this).text(), 10);
                    });
                    $('td:last-child', this.node()).html(Math.round(mySum * 2) / 2);
                });

                //j = 3;

                //while (j < nb_cols) {
                //    var pageTotal = api.column(j, { page: 'current' }).data().sum();
                //    $('#example thead tr:eq(1) th:eq(' + j + ')').html(Math.round(pageTotal * 100) / 100);
                //    j++;
                //}
            }

        });

        $('#mdlRetta').modal('show');

    }
```

I tried to change the code removing array of giorni and set objData as example:

```
{
    "DataArr": "2022-06-06T00:00:00",
    "DataPart": "2022-06-13T00:00:00",
    "Retta": 672,
    "NumPersone": 1,
    "Nome": "Formula Residence",
    "TipoCamera1": "DELUX",
    "NumCamera": "102",
    "NomeOspite": "RACCUGLIA AGATA ",
    "2022-06-05":"0",
    "2022-06-06":"0",
    "2022-06-07":"0",
    "2022-06-08":"0",
    "2022-06-09":"0",
    "2022-06-10":"0",
    "2022-06-11":"0",
    "2022-06-12":"0"
    ]
}
```

SOLVED:
I've add $('#tableretta').html(""); on unload modal event and that's it!

Comment: Please create a working, minimal, reproducible example of the issue.